# ImageResizing.net DiskCache plugin not working on IIS6

Tags: iis-6, umbraco, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm currently running an Umbraco v. 4.9.1 site on a server with IIS6. For this site I use the image cropping package, CropUp (which uses the ImageResizing.net plugin) and I have bought the DiskCache plugin for it to cache crops on the disc rather than in the memory.

I have installed the DiskCache plugin as follows:

- Copied the ImageResizer.Plugins.DiscCache.dll to the /bin folder of my site
- Added `<add name="DiskCache" />` to the `<plugins>` section in web.config
- Added `<diskcache subfolders="32" enabled="true" autoClean="false" dir="~/App_Data/ImageResizing" hashModifiedDate="true" />` to the `<resizer>` section in web.config.

And I have tried to insert this path to %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll on the "Home directory" tab under my sites properties in IIS.

Still, there's no folder in my `App_Data` folder called ImageResizing.

Does anyone know what I might have missed? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm - sounds legit, but I can't see all of your config. Here's a sample I got working on a site:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" />
      <section name="cropUp" type="Eksponent.CropUp.Config.CropUpSection, Eksponent.CropUp" />
    </configSections>
    <resizer>
      <plugins>
        <add name="DiskCache" />
        <add name="Eksponent.CropUp.Plugins.ImageResizerPlugin"></add>
      </plugins>
      <diskCache dir="~/media/imageresizer" />
    </resizer>
    <cropUp configSource="config\Eksponent.CropUp.config" />
</configuration>
```

Does this match your setup?

Comment: Hauge and Sniffdk: thanks a lot guys :-) I tried changing the path to ~/media/imageresizer and put the DiscCache plugin above the CropUp in <plugins> and not it works! :-) Thanks again!

Comment: It's likely that App_Data had incorrect permissions. If you had any kind of MSSQL DB in there, the MSSQL service will automatically 'break' your NTFS permissions every time it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure about how your complete setup looks, but it should look something like this. Generally, you should be able to make it work with the basic configuration:

```
<resizer>
    <plugins>
        <add name="DiskCache" />
        <add name="Eksponent.CropUp.Plugins.ImageResizerPlugin" />
    </plugins>
    <diskCache dir="~/App_Data/imagecache" />
</resizer>
```

Note, that I think diskCache etc. are case sensitive.